# Check Items of a listView if it is String.Empty

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have listview with 3 items and 1 subitems

So I would like to check if a row on item[3] is String.Empty.

if items[3] is empty it will not pass my items[3]  to label1.Text.
if items[3] is not empty it will pass my items[3] to my label1.Text
.

**this is my code**

```
if (listView1.Items[3].SubItems[1].Text == string.Empty)
{
    label1.Text = "";
}
else
{
    label1.Text = listView1.Items[3].SubItems[1].Text;
}
```

when my 3rd row is empty I got an error: InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'index'.

so how do i check the row if its empty and what validation should i do if it's empty i will not pass my items to label1.Text and if its not empty it will pass the Items to label1.Text

Comment: If you have 3 items, your index is 2.

Comment: indexing starts with `0` so the first element is at position `[0]` and so on...

Comment: Using Linq's `Skip()` and `Take()` and the null conditional operator might be safer if you arent 100% confident the indexes will be there.  Obviously will not be as fast but the difference should be very minor

Comment: I think [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm) might be helpfull

Comment: let's say i have 4 items what if my index[3] was empty? same question.
how do i check the row if its empty and what validation should i do if it's empty i will not pass my items to label1.Text and if its not empty it will pass the Items to label1.Text

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 items, So the maximum index is 2 because the index of the array count from 0.

Same principle for the subitem.

Use `Items[2]` and `SubItems[0]`

```
if (listView1.Items[2].SubItems[0].Text == string.Empty)
```

Comment: sir what if i have 4 items,  the Items[3] is empty. what should i do to not pass the item[3] to my label1? and if its not empty i will pass to my label1? Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Indexes in C# start at 0, so a collection that has 3 items would have the indexes of `0`, `1` and `2`.  Based on your question, your if statement should look like this:

```
if (listView1.Items[2].SubItems[0].Text == string.Empty)
```

When trying to access something by its index you should typically have some sort of safety check, like checking the `.Length` or `.Count` before attempting to access something that could be out of range.  You can also leverage some Linq and the null conditional operator to make things a little safer (albeit slightly slower since its enumerating):

```
//Skip 2, take the 3rd if its there then take the first SubItem. 
//label1.Text is either the text or an empty string
label1.Text = listView1.Items.Skip(2).FirstOrDefault()?.SubItems
                     .FirstOrDefault()?.Text ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < listView3.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                label1Text = listView3.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;
                label2Text = listView3.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;
                label3Text = listView3.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;
                

            } `
now i'am using this code i pass my 3 items to every labels. But it pass all same one items to all 3 labels

Comment: @user6767011 I have no idea what that code is supposed to represent.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes sir. I have 4 labels, each label represent to each rows or items in my listview. now i only have 3items that will pass to label1-3, and my 4th row or 3rd index is empty. so what should i do to not pass the empty item[3] to my label4.. Thankyou in advance!

Comment: @user6767011 have you actually tried my code yet?  Specifically the Linq stuff?